sveltekit client array available sporadically in reactive function
An app showing a list of building systems components with the ability to add a component. Database is Mongodb.
+page.js fetches the list, a definition of the table + populates "lookup" lists (to display text instead of _id on the list), returning all these things in data
page.svelte uses svelte component <GenericListView> passing in data.rows.components thus:
<div class="mt-2">
  Components
    <GenericListView
      definition="{data.subAssetDefinition}"
      data="{data.rows.components}"
      table="true"
      on:invalidate="{myInvalidate}"
    />
</div>

<GenericListView> builds a <table>, including a <TableRowTd> component:
{#each data as row}
  <tr on:click="{rowClick (row)}">
    {#each definition.tableFields as field}
      <TableRowTd
        {definition}
        {field}
        data="{row[field] || ''}"
      />
    {/each}
  </tr>
{/each}

Component <TableRowTd> has a $: function that takes the value in data (which is an _id) and searches through the appropriate list to match against the _id in the list and get the text.
$: {
  displayValue = data;
  let fieldDef = definition.schema.find (el => el.name == field);

  if (data && fieldDef && fieldDef.listType) {
    console.log (`<TableRowTd> looking up list for field [${field}], table [${fieldDef.table}] , id [${data}]`)
    try {
      console.log (definition.lists)
      let list = undefined;

      /* EDIT - changed array.find() to for( ... */
      console.log (`definition.lists.length [${definition.lists.length}]`);
      for (let i=0, found=false; i < definition.lists.length && !found; i++) {
        console.log (`Checking`);
        console.log(definition.lists[i]);
        if (definition.lists[i].table === fieldDef.table) {
          list = definition.lists[i];
          found = true;
        }
      }

      if (list) {
        console.log (`found the list`)
        let row = list.data.find (el => el._id === data);
        if (row) {
          console.log (`found`)
          displayValue = row.value;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('error on %s: %s', fieldDef.table, err.toString())
    }
  }
}

Everything works as desired on initial page load:

On adding an entry, the invalidate event is raised and passed up the stack - page.js' load function is called again.
However, now, in the $: function in <TableRowTd>, in the console, I can see the array of lists with all the data, but definition.lists.length is 0. Therefore I cannot match the _id to the text in the list:

Console log where we see the populated array, yet length property is 0:

How can this be? The array is available to console.log() but not my code? It "feels" like a Svelte (kit?) reactivity thing, the behaviour is sporadic, I am truly lost with this ...
